# Address of map value

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary

I have a settings which are stored in `std::map`. For example, there is `WorldTime` key with value which updates each main cycle iteration. I don't want to read it from map when I do need (it's also processed each frame), I think it's not fast at all. So,  can I get pointer to the map's value and access it? The code is:

```
std::map<std::string, int> mSettings;

// Somewhere in cycle:
mSettings["WorldTime"] += 10; // ms

// Somewhere in another place, also called in cycle
DrawText(mSettings["WorldTime"]); // Is slow to call each frame
```

So the idea is something like:

```
int *time = &mSettings["WorldTime"];

// In cycle:
DrawText(&time);
```

How wrong is it? Should I do something like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Best use a reference:

```
int & time = mSettings["WorldTime"];
```

If the key doesn't already exist, the `[]`-access will create the element (and value-initialize the mapped value, i.e. `0` for an `int`). Alternatively (if the key already exists):

```
int & time = *mSettings.find("WorldTime");
```

<sub>As an aside: if you have hundreds of thousands of string keys or use lookup by string key a lot, you might find that an `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` gives better results (but always profile before deciding). The two maps have virtually identical interfaces for your purpose.</sub>

Comment: But note that the second option is undefined if the item can't be found.

Comment: @MarkB: Certainly. The OP has to promise that the value exists :-) I've updated the post.

Comment: I realize that this is probably the best answer for his specific question, but I think my post has an interesting proposal for a design change that wouldn't require this sort of hack. What do you think?

Comment: @arasmussen: I agree that strings make poor ordered keys (see my smallprint). Beyond that I'm not familiar with the OPs needs, so I don't want to speculate too much. Your suggestion is certainly a very good general approach for any situation where it is applicable.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6438087/5987), it's perfectly OK to store a pointer to a map element as it will not be invalidated until you delete the element (see note 3).

Answer (score 2):

If you're worried so much about performance then why are you using strings for keys? What if you had an enum? Like this:

```
enum Settings 
{
    WorldTime, 
    ... 
};
```

Then your map would be using ints for keys rather than strings. It has to do comparisons between the keys because I believe std::map is implemented as a balanced tree. Comparisons between ints are much faster than comparisons between strings.

Furthermore, if you're using an enum for keys, you can just use an array, because an enum IS essentially a map from some sort of symbol (ie. WorldTime) to an integer, starting at zero. So then do this:

```
enum Settings 
{
    WorldTime, 
    ... 
    NumSettings
};
```

And then declare your mSettings as an array:

```
int mSettings[NumSettings];
```

Which has faster lookup time compared to a std::map. Reference like this then:

```
DrawText(mSettings[WorldTime]);
```

Since you're basically just accessing a value in an array rather than accessing a map this is going to be a lot faster and you don't have to worry about the pointer/reference hack you were trying to do in the first place.

Comment: I should add keys dynamically when I do need.

Comment: You need to dynamically add additional settings? Sounds fishy, but okay!

Comment: Yep, I'm writing game and some settings will be added dynamically by objects.

Comment: Are the settings of each of those objects known at compile time? You could generate the enum/array using a macro and simply paste all of the private members that you need to call DrawText on (Serializing?) using another macro.

Comment: But I guess that's adding a lot more hackage just to use arrays with ints instead of maps with strings. Good luck!

Comment: If you use enums (whose values you control) you can as well use an array! O(1).